# how to compare multiple rows in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

```
Given table:

create table borrower (
customer_number char ( 1 0 ) ,
loan_number char ( 1 0 ));
```

question: Find the customer number (i.e., ID) of every customer that shares all of the loans that customer “1234” has. If the customer whose customer number is “1234” has loans “L1” and “L2”, you need to find all customers (including customer “1234”) that share both “L1” and “L2”.

I have created 4 entries in the table for the columns (customer_number, loan_number) are (1234, L1) (1234, L2) (1, LI)(1, L2)(2, L1). I am using query

```
select distinct customer_number 
from borrower
where loan_number IN(
    select loan_number 
    from borrower 
    where customer_number='1234'
```

but it is retrieving output such as

```
1234, 1, 2
```

I want only 1  and 1234(Customer_number) in my output because it is the only one having both loan number L1 and L2. Cutsomer_number "2" is not associated with both the loan_number, so it should come in the out put.

I have also tried "all" in place of "IN".

```
select distinct customer_number 
    from borrower
    where loan_number= all(
        select loan_number 
        from borrower 
        where customer_number='1234'
```

output: nothing

Comment: Query using "IN" id select customer_number 
from borrower
where loan_number IN (
    select loan_number 
    from borrower 
    where customer_number='1234')         this query generate output 1234, 1234, 1, 1

Comment: In the meantime I am trying to find a solution, can u put your sample data in http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler so it would be easy for others to try. Also edit your question and share the URL with updated table structure in the above link

Comment: Query using "all" id select customer_number from borrower where loan_number = all ( select loan_number from borrower where customer_number='1234') this query does not retrieve any output

Comment: @Hogan I've updated the question. Please read it again.

Comment: @user3827844 -- ah thank you.  now the question makes sense.

Comment: `select b.customer_number, count(1) from borrower b 
inner join borrower x 
  on b.loan_number = x.loan_number and x.customer_number = 1234 
group by customer_number having count(1) = (select count(1) from borrower where customer_number = 1234)` ?  check in  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdb19/11/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a temporary table and a join.

```
/* create a table of the loans we are looking for */
create table Temp select distinct loan_number from Borrower 
where customer_number = '1234';

/* join against the temp table and select borrowers with 3 matches */
select customer_number as 'Match' 
from (select customer_number, COUNT(*) as C 
         from Borrower 
         inner join Temp on Borrower.loan_number = Temp.loan_number
         group by customer_number) X
where C = 3
```

Comment: but for large number of rows say 20000 or 50000, creating temp table could be inefficient

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Using an intermediate table with an index on loan_number would help. EDIT: the temp table probably wouldn't have very many loans in it, so the join ought to be pretty efficient.

Comment: can you submit your answer for the above mentioned statement?

Comment: Since we are joining on loan_number, putting an index on that column in the Borrower table will help the join, e.g. index ix_borrower_loan_number(loan_number).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As per OP's clarification

```
SELECT customer_number
FROM borrower b1
    WHERE b1.loan_number IN
    (SELECT loan_number FROM borrower
     WHERE customer_number=1234
     )
GROUP BY customer_number
HAVING count(*)=
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM borrower
   WHERE customer_number=1234)
```

Explanation: First I am counting the number of loans for the given customer_number. In this case, it should be `2`. Now I am comparing this count with each group of customer_number where the count is same.

Comment: I can suppress the rows using "distinct" as well but I want customer number who has both loans L1 and L2 not the L1 or L2. The query given by you also retrieve the rows which has only L1 loan_number as well.

Comment: Your sample data doesnt have any case like that. Give some more example

Comment: More table entries are like columns (customer_number, loan_number) are (1234, L1) (1234, L2) (1, LI)(1, L2) (2, L1) . In this (2, L1) is the new row entry in the table associated with only L1 loan but not L2. So this entry should not be retrieve. Only customer_number associated with both the loan_number (L1 and L2) should retrieve.

Comment: yes, it is working...but I didn't understand why you use GROUP BY customer_number
HAVING count(*)=
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM borrower
   WHERE customer_number=1234)    this part, can you explain this

Comment: It is to get the count `2` for `1234`. In case `1234` have 3 loans, the query would still work. I added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: If it worked for you, accept the answer so the question could be closed.

Comment: yes, I am accepting answer, can you explain one more thing why you put asterisk in count(*). That will be great

Comment: as I am grouping by `customer_number`, count(customer_number) and count(*) would work same way.

Comment: another observation from your query, this will work if no duplicate row is present in the table

Comment: I assume that combination of `customer_number` and `loan` is the primay key. If the table is designed properly, there should not be duplicates. If not I suggest to put a constraint to make sure that combination of load and customer is unique.

Comment: yes, I agree in this customer and loan are the primary key...Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I think you want only customer_number who have both loan L1 and L2. so you try this code for your table

**Query -**

```
SELECT customer_number
FROM
  (SELECT customer_number,
          loan_number
   FROM borrower
   WHERE loan_number IN (SELECT loan_number FROM borrower
 WHERE customer_number=1234)
   GROUP BY loan_number,
            customer_number)t
GROUP BY customer_number
HAVING count(*) =
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM borrower
   WHERE customer_number=1234)
```

If customer number not mentioned. But we need the customer list who are all applicable for all the loans like both L1 and L2

**Query2 -**

```
SELECT customer_number
FROM
  (SELECT customer_number,
          loan_number
   FROM borrower
   WHERE loan_number IN (SELECT distinct(loan_number) FROM borrower)
   GROUP BY loan_number,
            customer_number)t
GROUP BY customer_number
HAVING count(*) =
  (SELECT count(distinct(loan_number)) FROM borrower)
```

**Explanation for Query2**

`SELECT distinct(loan_number) FROM borrower`

```
loan_number
L1        
L2
```

The above query is used to find unique loans from borrower table.

```
SELECT customer_number, loan_number FROM borrower
   WHERE loan_number IN (SELECT loan_number FROM borrower
 WHERE customer_number=1234)
   GROUP BY loan_number, customer_number
```

```
customer_number    loan_number
1                   L1        
1234                L1        
2                   L1        
1                   L2        
1234                L2
```

This above query is used to find the customers who are all having the loans grouping based on their loans.

```
SELECT count(distinct(loan_number)) FROM borrower
```

The above code gives count 2 as output.(i.e., L1 and L2). In Query Having count(*) will check how many times customer_number will present. From this example, it prints customer_number who are all presenting two times in table.

Finally Query2 shows the output like

```
1         
1234
```

Final output remove customer_number 2 because he has only "L1". Both user 1 and 1234 has both loans "L1" and "L2"

Hope this code will helps you.

Comment: Hardcoding should be avoided as much as possible. Here `2` is not fixed. He just gave example and in real scenario, it might be more than that. So instead of getting `2` from hardcoding, you should use a subquery to give this count. Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Utsav. I updated my code.

Comment: instead use `SELECT count(*)
   FROM borrower
   WHERE customer_number=1234` to get the count of loans of only required customer

Comment: @Sahathulla still you are using hard static values (L1 L2)

Comment: @user3827844 now its updated based on your given user 1234

Comment: @Sahathulla Can you make this query more efficient? This query is retrieving my desired output, but still have some redundancy.

Comment: @pk786 can you explain little bit more. What exact output you want?

Comment: if customer_number=1234 is not given in the question then what will be the query for the same?

Comment: @pk786 I updated the Query 2 for you without customer_number. Is it helpful to you.?

Comment: @Sahathulla can you please explain this query?

Comment: @pk786 I updated the answer. Sorry, I am not well in English. Any grammatical error forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you execute all the sql sentense? looks like its ok:

```
select distinct customer_number 
from borrower
where 
  loan_number IN(
    select a.loan_number from borrower a where a.customer_number='1234'
  )
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment.

Comment: select distinct customer_number from borrower where loan_number IN( select a.loan_number from borrower a where a.customer_number='1234')     is running but not retrieving the desired output, but Now I got the way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I got another query to retrieve desired rows, this query may not work in MySQL because of EXCEPT

```
Select customer_number from borrower as b
where not exists
   (select loan_number from borrower where customer_number='1234')
except
   (select loan_number from borrower where customer_number=b.customer_number)
```